# difficulty setting up apache tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, installation

I am trying to install, run and do something with tomcat for the first time.

> apache-tomcat-7.0.16-windows-x86

I am running windows 7/firefox 4.0.

My first step is to run tomcat and be able to see some welcome screen on

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

I get the error that:
`Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8080.`

I connect to internet by using a data card, if this info is needed at all.

I have also downloaded/installed JDK,struts in the system, but I think the above step doesn't need or clash with these things.

Comment: Please take out some clues out of [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IX8xb-suzVg)

Comment: its resolved. just ran startup.bat from cmd in windows. Earlier, I was just clicking on it. Dont know why the difference, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with 
http://127.0.0.1:8080/

http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/